# Strange/impolite to request a faculty I've not met before to have a look at a postdoc research proposal I've written?

Tags: funding, postdocs, job, research-proposal, machine-learning

I'm submitting postdoctoral applications to a few places to receive external grants, and I've written a proposal all by myself. However, I'm planning to come back to academia after two years in industry that didn't go very well, and also my postdoc application subject (*statistical machine learning*) is significantly different from my PhD thesis topic (*differential geometry and low dimensional topology*) and also I was forced to divide my time in the US and Europe (in Europe now and planning to stay that way), so I'm feeling *academically isolated* and *I'm not fully confident that the research proposal will generate interests*.

So I think if I can contact a faculty member who works in the relevant directions, (s)he takes a look and gives me her/his honest opinion, I'll benefit a lot from it. However, since I'm *academically isolated* because of the reasons mentioned above, my only chance to write to a faculty who could be kind enough to take a look. **Just to make sure, I'm not planning to work with her/him directly - I would if I could but geographical constraints prevent me.** *So will it be strange or impolite to try my luck this way?* *And what will be the best way I can write my email and its subject to make sure (s)he takes a look?*

P.S. As mentioned in comments, no, my PhD advisor can't do anything here, even though he's a very accomplished pure mathematician, and I've all the respect for him.

P.P.S. The real problem is: I don't know people in person who do research in this topic.

Comment: Contacting people who know you is much more likely to be productive than contacting those who don't.

Comment: Perhaps your PhD supervisor would be a good place to start? even if the topic is unrelated they can likely give you good advice about the overall structure and general content.

Comment: @astronat, good idea. They may also be able to point the OP to someone who might help and even initiate the contact.

Comment: The way out of isolation is through people you know. I really don't understand why you are discounting your advisor or other faculty members you have interacted with in favor of cold emailing people.

Comment: If your proposal directly references someone's paper, and it's clear that you have read it, mastered it, and suggest plausible ideas on how to extend it, then if you're lucky you might get a response from that person. But keep in mind that there is **no** way to "make sure (s)he takes a look"; the same rule of etiquette that says its okay to email strangers also says that it's not obligatory to respond. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have any friends from your time in the PhD program? They could at least give this a first look and perhaps help your through their networks.

Comment: @Dawn Thanks for your comment - for the same reason I think my PhD advisor won't be of much help, my former pure math colleagues won't be as well, they simply don't know the field. However, I do have one or two friends who have moved onto industry but still publishes in ML. I can ask them, but it's just that I'm not sure it'd of much value - not downplaying their opinion, but I feel strongly that the people really know this specific area and published at least one paper are best suited to judge the research proposal. Unfortunately, I don't know these people in person :(

Comment: Right, but your proposal should be understandable to others without fully specialized knowledge. You also limit your risk of embarrassing yourself with the people you really want to weigh in by getting a pre-reading. Plus your current contacts also have a network of their own.

Comment: @Dawn so are you saying that I contact my former colleagues anyway to see if they can understand it, and if not, then forward it to some people in their network who are better suited to give me a pre-reading?

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for your comment! Say I email my advisor now whom I last saw in 2013, and then emailed a few times (last being in 2016), asking to take a look on a subject he doesn't work in, doesn't know (with due respect to him) where the state of the art really lies, and why this is beneficial from a practical point of view, what will he say? He'll probably say at best it looks mathematically a decent question to ask, but there's no way he'll be able to give a critical opinion. Past PhD, things are quite specialized.

Comment: @JonCuster conts) Maybe he'll be able to refer me to someone he knows who understands the topic better, and that's not a bad thing. It's just that during my time of PhD, I kind of know what his network is like, and I don't think he knows anyone who can do this, but I'll still think about it!

Comment: @ScienceMan - in the 7 or so years since you last saw them, how many new professors are there in the department? How many students have graduated since then, and do you know what their theses are on? At the very least, you should make the easy (re)connection in parallel with other more speculative avenues.

Answer (score 2):

When I was writing my grant proposal I was advised by professors to do exactly what you are describing, worst case scenario they're busy and they ignore you but it is not unpolite to ask.